# Debugging issue. Getting first 3 correct values and all others after are wrong

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me why in my vector is returning wrong values? First 3 values are correct but after that I get some wrong values into. I tried to save the values of the `shortest` variable from Function `findWaitingTime` . by pushing this value into my order vector. This should save the process Id so later on I can print it. For some reason after 3rd saved value all next are wrong.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int count1=0;
vector<int>burstT;
vector<int>Order;


 
struct Process {
    int pid; // Process ID
    int bt; // Burst Time
    int art; // Arrival Time
};
  
// Function to find the waiting time for all
// processes
void findWaitingTime(Process proc[], int n,
                                int wt[])
{
    int rt[n];
  
    // Copy the burst time into rt[]
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        rt[i] = proc[i].bt;
  
    int complete = 0, t = 0, minm = INT_MAX;
    int shortest = 0, finish_time;
    bool check = false;

    // Process until all processes gets
    // completed
    while (complete != n) {
  
        // Find process with minimum
        // remaining time among the
        // processes that arrives till the
        // current time`
           for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((proc[j].art <= t) &&
            (rt[j] < minm) && rt[j] > 0) {
                minm = rt[j];
                shortest = j;
                check = true;
                
            }
             
        }
        
        if (check == false) {
            t++;
            continue;
        }
        Order.push_back(shortest);
        // Reduce remaining time by one
        rt[shortest]--;
        // Update minimum
        minm = rt[shortest];
        if (minm == 0)
            minm = INT_MAX;
  
        // If a process gets completely
        // executed
        if (rt[shortest] == 0) {
  
            // Increment complete
            complete++;
            check = false;
  
            // Find finish time of current
            // process
            finish_time = t + 1;
  
            // Calculate waiting time
            wt[shortest] = finish_time -
                        proc[shortest].bt -
                        proc[shortest].art;
  
            if (wt[shortest] < 0)
                wt[shortest] = 0;
        
        
        }
        // Increment time
        t++;
        
    }
}
  
// Function to calculate turn around time
void findTurnAroundTime(Process proc[], int n,
                        int wt[], int tat[])
{
    // calculating turnaround time by adding
    // bt[i] + wt[i]
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        tat[i] = proc[i].bt + wt[i];
        
        burstT.push_back(proc[i].bt);
    }
}
  
// Function to calculate average time
void findavgTime(Process proc[], int n)
{
    int wt[n], tat[n], total_wt = 0,
                    total_tat = 0;
  
    // Function to find waiting time of all
    // processes
    findWaitingTime(proc, n, wt);
  
    // Function to find turn0 around time for
    // all processes
    findTurnAroundTime(proc, n, wt, tat);
  
    // Display processes along with all
    // details
    cout << "Processes "
        << " Burst time "
        << " Waiting time "
        << " Turn around time\n";
  
    // Calculate total waiting time and
    // total turnaround time
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        
        total_wt = total_wt + wt[i];
        total_tat = total_tat + tat[i];
        cout << " " << proc[i].pid << "\t\t"
            << proc[i].bt << "\t\t " << wt[i]
            << "\t\t " << tat[i] << endl;
        
    }
  
    cout << "\nAverage waiting time = "
        << (float)total_wt / (float)n;
    cout << "\nAverage turn around time = "
        << (float)total_tat / (float)n;
}
  

int main(int argc, char * argv)
{   
    int arrSize=0;
    vector<Process> procs;
    vector<Process> proc;
        int element1, element2, element3;
        char comma;
        ifstream infile("jobs.txt");
      
if (!infile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Can't open file" << endl;
}
else {
    while (infile >> element1 >> comma >> element2 >> comma >> element3)
    {
        Process proc{element1, element2, element3};
        procs.push_back(proc);
    }
}
    arrSize=procs.size();
cout << procs.size() << endl;

    int n = sizeof(proc) / sizeof(proc[0]);
  
  findavgTime(procs.data(), static_cast<int>(procs.size()));
int arrivalT=0;

cout<<endl;
     for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++){
         sort(burstT.begin(), burstT.end());
         arrivalT=arrivalT+burstT[i];
         cout << Order[i]+1<< "(" << arrivalT <<  "),";
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input file :

```
1,18,3
2,5,1
3,14,5
4,1,1
5,17,0
6,2,6
7,6,2
8,15,7
9,20,0
10,6,8
11,18,0
12,2,1
13,3,5
14,2,3
15,2,0
16,7,3
17,20,4
18,4,4
19,17,9
20,1,0
```

Printing vector Output:

```
20(1),4(2),12(4),12(6),14(8),14(10),6(13),6(17),15(22),15(28),13(34),13(41),
13(55),18(70),18(87),18(104),18(122),2(140),2(160),2(180),
```

How the output should be:

```
20(1),4(2),12(4),14(6),6(8),15(10),13(13),18(17),2(22),7(28),10(34),16(41),
3(55),8(70),5(87),19(104),1(122),11(140),9(160),17(180)
```

Comment: please add more details about the problem, and  perform some code cleanup, 
`cout << procs.size() << endl;
int n = sizeof(proc) / sizeof(proc[0]);`
both lines serve no purpose

Comment: int n is used later as argument of the function. and arrSize I use to print the elements from the vector at the end.